# rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.4, ~> 0.9) error in Jekyll serve --watch

Tags: jekyll

I have go following error while executing `Jekyll serve --watch`

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.4, ~> 0.9)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs': Your bundle is locked to minima (1.0.1), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of minima (1.0.1) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of minima (1.0.1) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.3.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.3.1/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>
```

I have used `bundle update` and and got following updates

```
Amar@Mac:~/Documents/www/jekyll-blog/amardhillon.com$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/................
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

  Password: 
Installing sass 3.4.23 (was 3.4.22)
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8 (was 0.9.7)
Using kramdown 1.13.1 (was 1.12.0)
Using liquid 3.0.6
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using rouge 1.11.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Installing minima 2.0.0 (was 1.0.1)
Using bundler 1.13.6
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using pathutil 0.14.0
Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.0 (was 1.4.0)
Using listen 3.0.8
Using jekyll-watch 1.5.0
Using jekyll 3.2.1
Bundle updated!
```

After this again when i executed  `jekyll serve --watch` then got same error. Any help is be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you run `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` those error messages should go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gem was installed using `sudo gem install rb-fsevent`